# Why does the likelihood function for the Poisson distribution integrate to $1$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability mass function for the Poisson distribution with parameter $\theta$ is

$$
\mathbb P(N=n;\theta)=\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^n}{n!}
$$

Since this is a probability mass function, we have:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P(N=n;\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^n}{n!}=1
$$

This is true for any distribution.  However, we also have:

$$
\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(N=n;\theta)d\theta=\frac1{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-\theta}\theta^n d\theta=1
$$

Since we are now integrating over $\theta$, rather than summing over $n$, the expression $\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^n}{n!}$ is more properly interpreted as the *likelihood function* for the distribution.  Likelihood functions do not, in general, integrate over their domain to give $1$.  What is special about the Poisson distribution that causes its likelihood function to have this property?

Comment: My previous answer indicated that the last integral is just the Gamma function. Obviously, the property exists because the Poisson pmf becomes the integrand of the Gamma function. What more are you looking for? Are you wondering if there is some reason that the distribution has an pmf that becomes the Gamma function? What is the source of the specialness you're looking for?

Comment: My main motivation for asking this question is to find a nice probabilistic interpretation for the gamma function integral.  So I want to find an answer that will tell me why the integral of the likelihood function is $1$ without actually having to evaluate the integral itself.  My guess is that the likelihood on its own is not going to be enough: indeed, if we make the substitution $\theta\mapsto\frac\theta 2$ then we still have a valid Poisson distribution, but the likelihood function now integrates to give you $\frac12$, not $1$.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: No, that can't be right, because it is the pdf of the Gamma distribution.

Comment: If $\tau = \frac{\theta}{2}$, then $\frac{d\tau}{d\theta} = \frac12$ and $d\theta = 2d\tau$.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  Sorry - I misremembered and phrased that quite badly.  My point is that $(e^{-2\theta}(2\theta)^n)/{n!}$ is a perfectly good pmf for the Poisson distribution (Poisson distribution with parameter $2\theta$).  But if you try integrating that from $0$ to $\infty$ then you make a substitution $\phi=2\theta$ and end up with $\frac12$ (because $d\phi=2d\theta$).

Comment: But that's completely unspectacular, because you're just differentiating with respect to "half" of the variable. It's exactly the same thing as computing $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} d\frac{t}{2}$

Comment: I'm not claiming that the result is spectacular, just pointing it out.  Yes, it is just the same as integrating with respect to 'half' the variable - the fact that this is just as meaningful as integrating with respect to the whole variable is what makes integrating the likelihood function a fairly meaningless operation.  Note that $(e^{-2\theta}(2\theta)^n)/n!$ still *sums* to $1$ if you sum over $n$: it is still a Poisson distribution, but its likelihood no longer integrates to give you $1$.  That is why I think you may well be right that there is no interesting answer to this question.

Comment: I have an incompletely developed idea about why things happen the way they do in your problem, and if it pans out, I will write an answer, but consider that if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is unknown, then upon observing that $X$ had
value $x$ on an experiment, the likelihood function is $$L(\mu; x) = f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(\mu-x)^2/2\sigma^2)$$ which, regarded as a function of $\mu$ with $x$, the data, being a constant, is also a density function, in fact that of a $N(x,\sigma^2)$ random variable.

Comment: It should be noted in the Poisson case, $\theta$ is fixed and the addends are all functions of $n$ and in the gamma case, it is $\mathbf{n}$ (which is taking the place of the shape $\alpha$) which is fixed and $\theta$ which is being summed over inside the integration—Not nexactly equivalent.

Comment: @Avraham - yes, I believe I said precisely that in my question....

Comment: @Donkey_2009 There is a similar phenomenon with the [beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaDistribution.html) and [binomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html) distributions. In the linked formulations, let $N = \alpha + \beta - 2$ and let $n = \alpha - 1$. The limits of integration may be different as the support for the beta's $x$ is [0, 1].